# special characters oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, special-characters

see I inserted a special character "µ" into my table over Oracle database:

```
INSERT INTO ABBREV (ABBREV, DEFINITION) VALUES ('µg','microgram (one millionth of a gram, 10-6 gram)');
INSERT INTO ABBREV (ABBREV, DEFINITION) VALUES ('µmole','micromole');
```

when I select the data I get:

```
SQL> select * from ABBREV where DEFINITION like '%micro%';

ABBREV                         DEFINITION
------------------------------ --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
omi                            other micro-organisms
¿µg                            microgram (one millionth of a gram, 10 -6 gram)
¿µmole                         micromole

SQL>
```

why I get "¿" before "µ" and how to avoid it in insert statement ?

```
Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.1.0.6.0
NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET         AL16UTF16
```

Comment: This [link](http://blogs.warwick.ac.uk/java/entry/how_to_retrieve/) may be helpful to you.

Comment: What is your client character set? You can use `dump()` to see which character is actually stored, which will show you if it's being lost on insert or just when displayed on query.

Comment: american_america.al32utf8

Comment: I made a trick at end of insert script: update ABBREV set ABBREV = substr(ABBREV,2) where 
DEFINITION in ('microgram (one millionth of a gram, 10-6 gram)','micromole'); This work fine for me, after executing query data display fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a proper solution you have to set your `NLS_LANG` environment variable according to your local codepage.

It looks like this:

```
C:\>chcp
Active code page: 850

C:\>set NLS_LANG=.WE8PC850

C:\>sqlplus ...

SQL> INSERT INTO ABBREV (ABBREV, DEFINITION) VALUES ('µmole','micromole');

1 row created.

SQL>
```

Another solution is to use function `UNISTR`:

```
INSERT INTO ABBREV (ABBREV, DEFINITION) VALUES (UNISTR('\00B5mole'),'micromole');
```